# Not getting product image urls of all products in json file?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, json

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
      foreach ($products as $_product) {
          array($_product->getData());
      }
    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($products->getData());
    echo $jsonData;
    file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to replace

```
array($_product->getData());
```

with

```
$array[] = $_product->getData();
```

For just getting image URLs instead of complete `data` you can use `$_product->getImageUrl()`.

---

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $array = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach ($products as $_product) {
        $array[] = $_product->getData();
    }

    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
    echo $jsonData;
    file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sv3n, now i will use this data on listing page, but still i want image urls for getting images on frontend, so can i get this in json file or I need to use this data for retriving the images and other data?

Answer (score 0):

The Product image URL can be taken by using product helper class.

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product , 'thumbnail');
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $array = array();
  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  foreach ($products as $_product) {
      $array[] = $_product->getData();
  }
  $gallery_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getMediaGalleryImages();
  $items = array();
  foreach ($gallery_images as $g_image) {
      $items[] = $g_image['url'];
  }

  $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array,$items);
  echo $jsonData;
  file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
  exit;
}
```

If I code like this, can I get image urls in my json file?